# Como executar comandos em postgresql

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Oi, eu estou fazendo um estágio em programação, no momento passando por cima de banco de dados, resolvi usar postgresql (foi horrível instalar, não sei ao certo se deu algo de errado na instalação pois tive que instalar o pgadmin4 manualmente e vejo muitos sites citando arquivos como psql.exe ou pgsql.exe que não sei onde estão)

Agora estou tentando criar tabelas no meu banco de dados, mas não faço ideia de como fazer isso, muitos sites dizem pra usar comandos como
`CREATE TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] (nome)` e eu simplesmente não sei onde usar eles, futuramente também tenho certeza que quando criar as tabelas não vou saber como conectar e usar comandos no meu script de python (principalmente pelo motivo que me confundo com a hud do vscode)

[Print do vscode (parte que não entendo)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpUfV.png)

O que começa a me complicar mais ainda é: depois que eu criar a tabela não sei como conectar a ela e usar comandos dentro do meu script, peguei um exemplo base de um site que vi e usava isso:

```
        conn = pgre.connect(
            host="",
            database="",
            user="",
            password=""
        )
```

(e depois usava cursor e cursor.execute, enfim)

se alguém puder me explicar de um modo simples essas duvidazinhas eu agradeceria muito

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Se quiser testar postgres sem precisar de sofrer tente [Supabase](https://supabase.com) (dá para instalar na sua máquina com cygwin). 

Tem o SQL Editor no dashboard onde pode rodar os comandos para rodar esses comandos.